# 25.000+ rows - MySQL SELECT consecutive numbers performance issue

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have tried to be as explicit as I could. Below you have the query explained in details

What I want to obtain?
 - I want to SELECT start_number and end_number from a set of consecutive numbers from a table

```
ex: 

    I have a column with values: 1,2,3,5,7,8,9,10
    If I run the SELECT on column will return: (1,3), (5), (7), (8,10)

    So my result will look something like :

    [
      'start_number' => 1,
      'end_number'  => 3
    ]
    .............
    .........
```

The problem is that the table contains a large number of rows (25.000+...for now) and it takes ages to execute (I have limited the number of results returned but still didn't fixed the execution time)

```
    SELECT 
        l.control_series AS start_control_series,
        (SELECT 
                MIN(a.control_series) AS id
            FROM
                cards AS a
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                cards AS b ON a.control_series = b.control_series - 1
            WHERE
                b.control_series IS NULL
                    AND a.control_series >= l.control_series) AS end_control_series
    FROM
        cards AS l
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
        cards AS r ON r.control_series = l.control_series - 1
    WHERE
        r.control_series IS NULL
    ORDER BY product_id ASC
    LIMIT 1;


Answer returned:

 [
  'start_control_series' => "110",
  'end_control_series'  => '114',
]

MySQLWorkbench response: 1 row(s)  returned 304.829 sec / 0.000 sec (as you can see it takes ages)
```

Table (cards) has 3 columns:

- row_id (int primary autoincrement)
- control_series (bigint)
- product_id (int)

Running MySQL 5.1, on a shared host

I'm want to return 10 results (LIMIT 1,10) in a fair amount of time

Thanks in advanced, hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: You should provide us with your database schema - just ONE table? What's all in it? This matters. Also, what's the distribution of the data? Does it cluster or is it "flatly" distributed throughout its domain? Yes, you gave us queries, but your problem description is far from clear. In your opening statement, the pattern was completely indiscernable. Finally, as _partial_ answer, there is NO connection between limiting the number of rows returned and finding the RIGHT answer and being able to return even the first single row; the problem isn't returning rows, it's finding the right answer.